# Accessing custom options of an order in Magento via PHP

Tags: php, magento

I'm loading an order like this:

```php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(2886);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
```

Then I use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item){
    $name[] = $item->getName();
    $unitPrice[]=$item->getPrice();
    $sku[]=$item->getSku();
    $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
    $qty[]=$item->getQtyToInvoice();
}
```

And I am able to get most of the data I need.  However, I'm having problems getting the custom options that were selected for the order.  I can see the data in a var dump, but I have had no success in mining it out.  I've also tried a handful of built in functions that I found via google, but no luck.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it (yes that works!). This will mark your question as solved (that's how SO works) and it will help others! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822235/matt) (OP) already self-answered the question.

Quote:

---

I was able to get what I needed by using:

```
$opts = $item->getProductOptions();
```

Within my foreach loop.  A var_dump on that shows how to access the data easily.

Answer (score 2):

As Nuno Furtado stated above, this returns nothing in **Magento 1.8+**.

My solution was:

```
$opts=$item->getData('product_options');
$opts=unserialize($opts);
print_r($opts);
```